# File not in use, yet cannot be removed

Tags: windows, windows-10, process

I cannot remove executable because windows explorer says its in use.

But both Resource Monitor and Process Explorer claim this file is not used. IObit Unlocker also says that file is not locked. So I'm stuck with unremovable file. I can format that hard drive, but I'm certain there is another solution.

Comment: Log on as a different Admin user and try removing it that way. I also use Unlocker 1.92 (MajorGeeks)

Comment: @John I don't have other users but I guess I can make one. Unlocker failed too.

Comment: Also try LockHunter, https://lockhunter.com/ and set the file to be deleted after *reboot*. Another possibility is that it's part of anti-malware; uninstall the anti-malware suite to remove its components. Some suites require a special tool from the software vendor.

Comment: Rename it to another extension and reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to deal with stubborn files is to boot to a Linux Live CD/USB and navigate via command line to the appropriate folder.

Comment: Most live distros now have fully fledged DE, so it's simple enough to click around like windows, and delete anything you like. Warning to OP though, windows might shit. It obviously thinks it wants that file.